# loading file in 98 Hugs

Tags: haskell

I am using Hugs 98 and I am trying to load a file like this

:load insert.hs

and keeps saying

- Unable to open file "insert.hs"

I am new to Haskell

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've worked with ghc/ghci, but never with Hugs; so I'm helpless for your question.... but I'm curious about why do you prefer to use Hugs over ghc.

Comment: Not hugs-specific, but does the file `insert.hs` exist?  Is it in the current directory?  Is it available for reading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try entering `:! dir` (if you're on Windows) or `:! pwd; ls` (on Linux) at the Hugs prompt: that will show you the current directory and its contents - it should have 'insert.hs' in it.

If that's not the case, do `:cd <location of insert.hs>` and you should be able to `:load insert.hs` after that.

But like dsign said in the comments, consider upgrading to GHC - Hugs is more than 6 years out of date!

Comment: I am new to Haskell and for our assignment we are required to use Hugs.

Comment: @codeeeeeNOT Tell your prof/TA he should get with the times! He can come and argue with the rest us by asking a question "As a teacher, why should I prefer Hugs over the latest version of GHC?". Hugs is, as far as I know, not even Haskell2010 compliant.